# Позировать камерам или позировать перед камерами?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно, **позировать камерам** или **позировать перед камерами**?

Comment: Позируют как, для, где и кому. Профессионально, для портфолио, в студии, скульптору.

Comment: Из правил: Когда не следует оставлять комментарий?
Комплименты, не содержащие новой информации («+1, великолепный ответ»); вместо этого, проголосуйте за данный ответ и поделитесь своей репутацией. 
Благодарите за ответы на ваши вопросы
Ваше простое искреннее «спасибо» очень ценно, но это не все, чем вы можете отблагодарить ответившего: проголосуйте за ответы, которые вам больше всего помогли

Answer (score 1):

**ПОЗИРОВАТЬ**

**1.** Приняв определенное положение, служить моделью художнику, фотографу или объектом для съемки.

*В объявлениях моделей, кроме того, не должно допускаться указания на согласие **позировать для любителей** и на цену за сеансы.*
***Позировать для*** парадного портрета. **Позировать в** обнажённом виде, **в** театральном костюме, **в** повседневном платье. **Позировать перед** **камерами, перед** фотоаппаратом.

**2.** *перен.* Принимать позу, стараться произвести впечатление своим поведением, словами, внешностью; рисоваться.

*Гвардеец опять ничего не говорит, а только **позирует** своей стройной **фигурой** на фоне убогой бархатной портьеры.*
***Позировать перед*** зеркалом; **позировать перед** слушателями. **Позировать** **перед** самим собой (воображать себя).

**3.** *устар.* Создавать положение, известность, репутацию.

*Роман с Загоровским **позировал** Таису Николаевну, как всегда **позирует** некрасивую женщину ухаживанье красивого и женатого мужчины.*

**Правильно будет *"позировать перед камерами"*.**
[Словарь галлицизмов](http://gallicismes.academic.ru/30314)

Comment: Спасибо. Стало настолько понятно, будто сам всегда это знал)

Comment: Рада помочь. Благодарное слово всегда приятно.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно позируют **художнику, фотографу** (одушевленные лица) и **позируют перед камерами, перед фотоаппаратом** (неодушевленные предметы).

Из словаря:

**ПОЗИРОВАТЬ**,  [от франц. poser] 1. Приняв определённое положение, служить моделью художнику или объектом для съёмки. П. **перед фотоаппаратом, телекамерой.**

Примеры:

Ксения не растерялась и стала позировать **перед фотокамерами.** Я почему-то никогда не стремилась позировать **художникам.** Раньше хоть и редко, но удавалось позировать **фотографу**, сняться в какой-либо рекламке.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно.